# Unit Testing Caliburn.Micro ViewModels

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I'm developing Windows Phone 7 app using MVVM approach with Caliburn.Micro. How do I test my ViewModels? They all look like this (simplified):

```
public class MainPageViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {
        readonly INavigationService navigationService;

        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;               
        } 
}
```

The `INavigationService` is defined in Caliburn.Micro assembly and the problem is that it inherits from `INavigate` which is defined in System.Windows (Windows Phone version). So when I try to use such ViewModels in unit test project I get the following error

> The type 'System.Windows.Controls.INavigate' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0,

When I try to add explictly the reference to System.Windows.dll that is used in my WP7 project I get the .NET version (4.0.x.x) added instead. My VMs are defined in WP7 project, I can't move them to portable class library, because Caliburn.Nicro does not support PCL yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you create a WP7 class library for your unit tests?

Comment: Looks like I can't add reference to Microsoft UniTesting Framework in WP7 projects.

Comment: Ah. Have you tried using an alternative unit testing framework?

Comment: I still hope there is another way, I also have WebAPI project backend and all the tests for it are written using MS UnitTestFramework. Would be really disappointing to have to change frameworks because one single INavigate interface with one single method is defined in WP7-specific library. I don't even need it, Mock or null would do for my scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the custom Unit Test Framework as described in [nokia developer wiki](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_unit_test_with_the_Windows_Phone_Toolkit_Test_Framework). Additional benefit from using it is that I can directly test my phone-specific implementations without need of using mocks